# How to convert PNG to ICO so it doesn't get resized

Tags: icons, png, desktop-icons

I have this small icon:

[image: ico]

The problem is that it gets resized whenever I use it for my application:

[image]

I need it to stay it at 16x16 and not get bigger. Note I'd need to do the same with more than one icon so I prefer automatical way to achieve this. I also have PNG sources of all icons if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make it so it won't resize,that's just how Windows works.  However, you could create a 32x32 icon that was all transparent except for the 16x16 block where you have the original icon.